# "new tags" page lost the page numbers

Tags: bug, status-norepro, tags

I distinctly recall that this morning, there were page numbers at the bottom of the ["new tag"](https://physics.stackexchange.com/tags?tab=new) page on Physics.SE:

[image]

Now, these buttons are missing. There's also an ugly `overflow:scroll` bar. And it's *not* endless scrolling, it just shows the first page of the new tags. There is absolutely no way to access page 2. [Even my trusty friend, URL manipulation, doesn't work](https://physics.stackexchange.com/tags?page=2&tab=new).

I see the same behavior [on MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags?tab=new), sans the scrollbars.

[image]

Please bring this back, page-by-page navigation is useful when auditing tags. [No matter what Jeff says.](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/03/the-end-of-pagination.html)

Tried on both Chrome dev and beta--so it's not the fault of a millisecond update(I think).

Also on iPad (the scrollbars go away though)

Note that I don't care much about the scrollbars, my main issue is with the spiriting away of page 2 etc. Just thought I'd mention them cause they could be connected--they weren't there this morning either.

UPDATE:

It seems like some sites, like [Super User](https://superuser.com/tags?tab=new) and [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags?tab=new) have pagination. I'm beginning to suspect that this is by design--maybe tags that are xyz days old are removed from the list? That would explain the disappearences of page numbers on Physics and MSO.

If so, could this be changed to show all tags sorted by date? This is a very useful sorting option when cleaning tags up.

Comment: Do you really need page numbers if there's only one page? I agree the scrollbars are annoying...

Comment: @animuson its not endless scrolling. That's the point--there is no way to access page 2. And we do HAVE a page 2 on that page, I used it this morning. See edit.

Comment: Are you sure? The fact that there are two blank spaces left at the end suggests that page one is *not* filled. Also, changing the page manually to `2` produces an empty page.

Comment: @animuson [no blank spaces here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags?tab=new) . Like I said, I used it this morning and it had about 9 pages. The list may be clearing itself of xyz old tags, but I don't want that either.

Comment: You sure you weren't on the "popular" or "name" tabs?

Comment: @Bobby: Yep, I'm sure. [SU](http://superuser.com/tags?tab=new) and [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/tags?tab=new) have pagination. I was specifically trawling through the new tags looking for tags that ought to be burninated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[I see tag pages](https://i.imgur.com/7bxfIwv.jpg) -- even though you only have one page, going to [your manipulated URL](https://physics.stackexchange.com/tags?page=2&tab=new) proves that the paginator is indeed there.